# Problems reading edited data after modifying data file using fstream in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm currently making a record system for ticket booking as an assignment and facing problems when I want the data to read after modifying my file. **I saw there were 2 options for me: eof or read in fstream.**

**The code for my modify records:**

```
            ifstream inFile;
            ofstream outFile;
            inFile.open("movieRecord.dat");
            outFile.open("temp.dat");
            
            inFile >> item.movieName >> item.movieTime >> item.hallNum >> item.moviePrice;
            
            cout << "\tPlease Enter the Movie to Edit:";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(editMovie,20);
            
            titleMatch = strcmp (editMovie,item.movieName);
            
            while (!inFile.eof()){
                if (editMovie == item.movieName){   
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    outFile << item.movieName << " " << item.movieTime << " " << item.hallNum << " " << item.moviePrice << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            cout << "\tEditing " << editMovie << "..." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cout << "\tReInsert Movie Title: ";
            cin.getline(movieTitle,20);
                                        
            cin.clear();
            cout << flush;
            cout << "\tEnter Time(ie:15.00): ";
            cin >> movieTime2;
                                            
            cout << flush;
            cout << "\tEnter Hall Number for Movie: Hall ";
            cin >> hallNumber;
                                                
            cout << flush;
            cout << "\tEnter Price of Movie Ticket: RM";
            cin >> ticketPrice;
                                
            outFile << movieTitle << " " << movieTime2 << " " << hallNumber << " " << ticketPrice;  
        
            outFile.close();
            inFile.close();
                    
            remove ("movieRecord.dat");
            rename ("temp.dat","movieRecord.dat");
            cout << "\tEdit Saved!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            goto adminMenu;
        }
```

**My code for reading the file:**

```
            ifstream movieCheck;
            movieCheck.open("movieRecord.dat",ios::in);
            movieCheck >> item.movieName >> item.movieTime >> item.hallNum >> item.moviePrice;
            
            if (!movieCheck.good()){
                cout << "File Open Error!" << endl;
            }
            while (movieCheck.read((char*)&item,sizeof(item))){
                cout << "\tMovie title: " << item.movieName << endl;
                cout << fixed;
                cout << "\tTime: " << setprecision(2) << item.movieTime << endl;
                cout << "\tHall Number: Hall " << item.hallNum << endl;
                cout << "\tMovie Ticket Price: RM " << setprecision(2) << item.moviePrice << endl;
                cout << "\t==============================================" << endl;
                movieCheck >> item.movieName >> item.movieTime >> item.hallNum >> item.moviePrice;
            }
            
            movieCheck.close();
            cout << endl << "\t The End of the Movie Summaries!" << endl;
```

When I use eof, the output will only show the first data only, simple example:

**Desired Output:**

Hello

Help2 \The edited record

**Current Output:**

Hello \does not show the edited record

When using read function however, my output is either similar to eof or it would not show at all.

Comment: Your `while` is just an `if` because of the `break`s.

Comment: If I do not put the break in the while, the code would not read the next line. Is there a way  to go through this?

Comment: Without the `break`, how would your loop ever end?